# GUIDs vs OBJECTID

Tags: web-services, soap, guid

I am devising a program that consumes the Sharepoint 2010 SOAP web services. One of the methods uses the Web Search service Query method that retrieves a bunch of results, of which neither are GUIDs. It does however return the URL of each results. The webs web-service has a class member 'GetObjectIdFromUrl' method that retrieves the ObjectId.

However, I am unable to find any information online if ObjectId and GUID are the same. By name alone, they are not.

If they are not, can anybody provide cues as to how I can retrieve GUIDs for search results. One rationale would be to mention in the Query XML before consuming the search API that the GUID needs to be returned by encoding in `<Properties><Property name = "GUID"/></Properties>`

Answer (score 0):

An object id is the general term for a GUID of a sharepoint object (Site, item, list, etc)
[Logic exstracted from here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2410139)

Comment: oh cool, so they are technically the same, I wonder why a generalization for ObjectId exists when GUID suffices in any case, but thanks !